# Laravel how to get response from other application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I had to send a URL to another application for payment processing to a payment API inside a form. So when users of their website click on the link it will redirect them to my site. But the problem is when it redirects them to my site, they see that route is not found error though I have that route in my web.php.
How do H solve this issue?

Suppose I have sent the following value through the form to other website:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{asset('shop-cancel/'.$tran_id)}}" />
```

And this is the route of my webiste:

```
Route::get('shop-cancel/{itemid}','BillingsController@shopCancel');
```

Comment: above hidden input value is in form of first application and you want to send it to other application ? Am I right ?

Comment: What is the url they are redirecting back?

Comment: Yes ..and redirect to 1st application

Comment: they redirect the url same as i have given ..like  ..`www.abc.com/shop-cancel/87495`

Comment: Typically payment APIs would accept a return url for sucessful transactions. I'm willing to bet that they won't accept this url under the input name `cancel_url` . You should refer to the 3rd party API's manual. Also `asset` is not a url to a route, you need `url("shop-cancel/".$tran_id)`

Comment: I used url but i was getting same Error. then i changed the url from `get` to `post` ..then it redirects to my site but it's showing `csrf token` error.for that i wrote `shop-cancel/{itemid}` inside `protected $except` array in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` but seeing the `csrftokern` error again.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

> `asset('shop-cancel/'.$tran_id)`

use

> `url('shop-cancel', [$tran_id])`

This gives fully qualified route. Detail documentation can be found here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url

Comment: I used url but i was getting same Error. then i changed the url from `get` to `post` ..then it redirects to my site but it's showing `csrf token` error.for that i wrote `shop-cancel/{itemid}` inside `protected $except` array in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` but seeing the `csrftokern` error again.

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your route, make it post type and make argument optional:

```
Route::get('shop-cancel/{itemid?}','BillingsController@shopCancel')->name('route.name');
```

Exclude this route from your VerifyCsrfToken Middleware:

```
protected $except = [
 route('route.name'),
];
```

Then use the route helper:

```
route('route.name',['itemid' => $item_id]);
```

Comment: I used url but i was getting same Error. then i changed the url from `get` to `post` ..then it redirects to my site but it's showing `csrf token` error.for that i wrote `shop-cancel/{itemid}` inside `protected $except` array in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` but seeing the `csrftokern` error again.

Answer (score 0):

asset is use for images,css,js links. You have to use url function to redirect to your cancel url

```
Try This
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="{{url('shop-cancel/'.$tran_id)}}" />
```